# Generator results

Tags: python, dictionary

i want to make an app for my work so i take notes of packages i send to my clients
so i have a dictionary with my client list and their code numbers
what i want my app to do is to import multiple code numbers compare them with the keys in my dictionary and get the items back.... because the code numbers cannot be integers i have to manipulate them as a string chunk them up with a generator and get the results back

```
farmcod = { "0039":"ΑΤΣΑΛΗ Μ.","0056":"ΒΑΡΔΙΑΜΠΑΣΗΣ Κ.",  
"0138":"ΒΟΥΜΒΟΥΡΑΚΗ Α.","0047":"ΓΕΩΡΓΟΥΛΑΚΗ Κ.","0087":"ΓΟΥΜΕΝΑΚH 
Κ.","0035":"ΓΥΠΑΡΗ Ε.",}

def chunker(seq, size):
return [seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size)]

kodfain = input ('pharmacy key : ') 

for group in chunker(kodfain, 4):

print (group,",",sep="",end='')
```

so if i input 006900780054 i get ===>  0069,0078,0054,

my question is how i can compare those 3 generator results  compare them to the keys of dictionary and get the items back?

Comment: Indentation is important in Python. Can you please indent your code properly?

Comment: Where's the generator? I don't see any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
farmcod = {"0039": "ΑΤΣΑΛΗ Μ.", "0056": "ΒΑΡΔΙΑΜΠΑΣΗΣ Κ.",  "0138": "ΒΟΥΜΒΟΥΡΑΚΗ Α.",
           "0047": "ΓΕΩΡΓΟΥΛΑΚΗ Κ.", "0087": "ΓΟΥΜΕΝΑΚH Κ.", "0035": "ΓΥΠΑΡΗ Ε.", }


# this returns a list, not a generator. Shouldn't matter unless your dataset is huge
def chunker(seq, size):
    return [seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size)]

kodfain = "006900780054"

for group in chunker(kodfain, 4):
    code = farmcod.get(group, None)
    if code:
        # do something with the code
        print(code)
    else:
        # it wasn't found
        print('code not found for', group)
```

Some notes:

- If speed is important and you expect most of your groups to be in `farmcod`, you might want to use a `try-catch` block instead of the `if-else` block. It might be faster.
- Your `chunker` function returns a list, not a generator. If your data set is small, that's okay. If not, research generator functions.

Comment: you can skip it entirely and just do `code = farmcod.get(group, 'code not found for {}'.format(code))` and then print it.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis You could if all you want to do is print it, but if you want to prompt a user for the code or do some error handling (and I'm certain he'll want to do something special in the failure case), you'll have to reintroduce the `if-else` anyway.

Comment: @NikolaosGasparis That's a different question. But it looks like you want a `while` loop. Google 'input loop python' and mangle what you find until it does what you want :) .

Comment: the user will import multiple codes each time so i need the input to loop for infinite times until the user breaks the loop 
i tried to put directly the input results into a list but i cannot make make an iterator to spilit the chars in groups of 4 the result i get is [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] instead of [1234,5678] if i had the second list at least i would find a way to compare the strings with the keys and get the items back

Comment: @NikolaosGasparis so put the code above into an input loop and update the dictionary each iteration.

Comment: thank you mate you sorry for silly questions im just beginning :D

Comment: @NikolaosGasparis No worries; it can be hard but it's worth learning. I would suggest you read a few books or tutorials though. Check out some of the links on the 'Online Books and Resources' on the right sidebar at https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/ . But you're going to learn the most doing projects like this one :)